# Keep always running Go http server app inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, httpserver

I have a `Docker` container that runs just a `Go` binary I created that is a http server with `Gin` framework. I don't use any other Web Server, just Go's internal http server. Inside my `Dockerfile` at the end of file I have this:

```
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/home/project/microservices/backend/engine/cmd/main"]
```

I use `docker-compose` to run the container and `restart: always` for each container. And it works!

But my question is that, if the http server that I created fails due to programming error or something, It will restart? how can I check this? does Docker has tools for this?

I tried go with `Supervisord` but it has some problems and I was not successful on running it.

I want a workaround to keep the http server inside container always running.

What can I do?

Comment: it will always restart if the app exits. why don’t you create an error so you can see it for yourself? It’s a good experiment. I will also add a health check to the docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try killing the process from the host. Find the process id using something like

```
ps -aux | grep main
```

Then kill it using

```
sudo kill <process id>
```

Docker will then restart it. By using

```
docker ps
```

you should see that the 'status' has changed to something like `Up 10 seconds`.